# Can I compile without including SDL in my header?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2, vcpkg

I've been trying to get SDL2 working in Visual Studio after installing SDL with `vcpkg`. I've used SDL2 with C and C++ with `makefiles`, and it has worked fine for me. I copied over some C++ code that was previously working with a `make` file, but when using Visual Studio, it's no longer is able to compile. I kept getting an error on the header file that it's because it doesn't recognize the SDL identifiers.

With my `makefile`, I don't need to include `SDL2/SDL.h` in my header file, just in my `cpp` file.  Visual Studio isn't letting me do the same thing.  Is it just a setting that I'm missing?  Do I truly need to include the `SDL2/SDL.h` in my header file as well?

I have a portion of the code pasted below.  Errors are being thrown for `SDL_Window`, `SDL_Renderer`, and `SDL_Color`.

```
//Handler.hpp
#ifndef HANDLER_H_
#define HANDLER_H_

//#include <SDL2/SDL.h> // <- Without this it throws errors

class Handler
{
public:

//variables
SDL_Window * window;        //A pointer to the window being handled
SDL_Renderer * renderer;    //A pointer to the renderer for the window
unsigned int window_x;      //The width of the window
unsigned int window_y;      //The height of the window
SDL_Color render_color;     //The current drawing color of the renderer
Handler();
Handler(std::string title, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, bool resizable = false, SDL_Color color);
~Handler();
}
#endif //HANDLER_H_
```

And then I have this file, which includes `SDL2/SDL.h`.  This was enough before when using `makefiles`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "Handler.hpp"

/* ------ Constructors ------ */

Handler::Handler()
{
    window_x = DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE;
    window_y = DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        window_x, window_y, 0);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    render_color = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, render_color.r, render_color.g, render_color.b, render_color.a);

}

Handler::Handler(std::string title, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, bool resizable, SDL_Color color)
{
    window_x = x;
    window_y = y;

    int flags{ 0 };
    if (resizable)
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        window_x, window_y, flags);

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    render_color = color;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, render_color.r, render_color.g, render_color.b, render_color.a);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

/* ------ Deconstructor ------ */
Handler::~Handler()
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio is compiling your header separately, perhaps you can disable that somehow and only compile .cpp files. But still, the good practice would be to not require any particular order when using header files (and this would mean including SDL in the header).

Comment: Do you use `-include` flags in your Makefile (which might be used for pre-compiled-header).

Comment: Is it really a compiler error you got, or just Intellisense one?

Comment: @Jarod42 I have build errors only selected and its giving me a bunch of errors telling me things like missing type specifier right after the SDL types.

Comment: @Jarod42 I also was using just an include path in my makefile because I had them separated into different folders and set up as a standalone project.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yea, It does seem to be compiling it separately.  Do you happen to know how I would disable that?  I think that's all it is, but I can't find a setting for that anywhere

Comment: [OT]: Your class doesn't follow rule of 3/5/0. -> `Handler(const Handler&) = delete;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the heads up, I've not heard of this rule.  I just started C++ after taking a class in C last semester and have been self-teaching it all, and I am horrid at self teaching

Comment: @QuintonGraham If you must include `SDL2/SDL.h` in the `.cpp` file, you could just declare the `SDL_` types as a `void*` and then cast them when using them in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: If you want to hide SDL stuff in header, [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use forward declarations for `SDL_Window` and `SDL_Renderer`, not sure about `SDL_Color`.

Comment: Do you have a way I could go about that?  I'm not positive how you mean.  If you are just going for the structure of the struct, the renderer and window structs are incomplete types i think